# Mock-testing the catch block of a promise method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

My method is:

```
getFilterData(filterFields, comparisons, filterValues) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      axios.post('/projects/filter', {
        filter_fields: filterFields,
        comparisons,
        filter_values: filterValues,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            projectData: response.data,
            isFilterModalOpen: false,
          }, resolve(response));
        })
        .catch(this.handleRequestError);
    });
  }
```

I tried writing a test:

```
describe('When getFilterData() is unsuccessful', () => {
  it('calls handleRequestError', async () => {
      axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(HREResponse));
      const app = await global.shallowWithIntl(<ManageProjectsPage />).dive();
      const spy = jest.spyOn(app.instance(), 'handleRequestError');
      await app.instance().getFilterData(['language'], ['='], ['Java'])
        .catch(error => expect(error).toBe(HREResponse));
      console.log(app.instance().state);
      app.update();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      spy.mockRestore();
     });
     axios.post.mockReset();
   });
```

The error says, expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
More details:

1. The filter is defined as a post method.
2. HREResponse has status 504, which is the status handleRequestError receives.

Comment: Where does `shallowWithIntl` come from? Which library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `const spy = jest.spyOn(app.instance(), 'handleRequestError');` it spy for instance X.

`await app.instance().getFilterData(['language'], ['='], ['Java']) .catch(error => expect(error).toBe(HREResponse));` running on instance Y, with `handleRequestError` is not been spy.

Just use one app instance when you test it.

```
describe('When getFilterData() is unsuccessful', () => {
  it('calls handleRequestError', async () => {
    axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(HREResponse));
    const app = await global.shallowWithIntl(<ManageProjectsPage />).dive();
    
    const instance = app.instance(); // create app instance

    const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleRequestError'); // spy on the instance
    await instance.getFilterData(['language'], ['='], ['Java']) // execute on the instance
      .catch(error => expect(error).toBe(HREResponse));
    console.log(instance.state);
    app.update();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    spy.mockRestore();
  });
  axios.post.mockReset();
});
```